# Experience Profile JS error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Message' of undefined

Tags: experience-profile

I'm using Sitecore 9.0.1, i'm getting this error in console when opening the experience profile dashboard and it returns no contacts.
It looks like this error is due to the ajax response of the following api :
 /sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search?&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&.....

[image]

I checked the Xconnect logs and got the following error

```
[Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.SetFacetOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Facet]: 
Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException: Operation #1, 
AlreadyExists, Contact {3ef744bc-bd5b-0000-0000-055d7358d781}, PhoneNumbers
```

Update:

After checking the cm logs again i found this Error

`Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Message: Method not found: 'Void Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract.set_ParametrizedConstructor(System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo)'.
Source: Sitecore.XConnect
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Serialization.SearchQueryContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient.<Search>d__9`1.MoveNext()`

Any idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: Your request status is 500. Check logs for more details

Comment: Check Solr is working or not....

Comment: It looks like the JS that executes that request included some `null` values in the query string. Can you look to see where that request is being executed and why they're null?

Comment: I checked the logs and got the following error [Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.SetFacetOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Facet]: Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException: Operation #1, AlreadyExists, Contact {3ef744bc-bd5b-0000-0000-055d7358d781}, PhoneNumbers
Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: Do you have full stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating i found that this error was due to the following api: /sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search?&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1&..... returning null. 
And the reason this api returning null is that i was using a "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" version 11 in which the function "set_ParametrizedConstructor" was obsolete So the json response couldn't be deserialized. 
Replacing the Newtonsoft.Json.dll version 11 with version 9.0.1 solved the problem.